# Полный вывод запроса mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть запрос:

```
<?php
    $host="localhost";
    $user="admin";
    $pass="pass";
    $db_name="base";
    $link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `steamid`, `nickname`, `Russia`, `Canada`, `United States of America`, `Mexico`, `Guatemala`, `El Salvador`, `Belize`, `Honduras`, `Nicaragua`, `Costa Rica`, `Panama`, `Cuba`, `Haiti`, `The Bahamas`, `Jamaica`, `Dominican Republic`, `Puerto Rico`, `Greenland`, `Iceland`, `Colombia`, `Venezuela`, `Trinidad and Tobago`, `Ecuador`, `Guyana`, `Suriname`, `Peru`, `Brazil`, `Bolivia`, `Paraguay`, `Chile`, `Argentina`, `Uruguay`, `Falkland Islands`, `Antarctica`, `Ireland`, `United Kingdom`, `Norway`, `Sweden`, `Finland`, `Estonia`, `Latvia`, `Denmark`, `Portugal`, `Spain`, `France`, `Belgium`, `Luxembourg`, `Netherlands`, `Switzerland`, `Italy`, `Germany`, `Lithuania`, `Austria`, `Slovenia`, `Czech Republic`, `Poland`, `Slovakia`, `Hungary`, `Croatia`, `Bosnia and Herzegovina`, `Montenegro`, `Albania`, `Greece`, `Macedonia`, `Kosovo`, `Bulgaria`, `Republic of Serbia`, `Romania`, `Moldova`, `Belarus`, `Ukraine`, `Turkey`, `Georgia`, `Azerbaijan`, `Armenia`, `Northern Cuprus`, `Cuprus`, `Syria`, `Lebanon`, `Palestine`, `Israel`, `Jordan`, `Iraq`, `Iran`, `Saudi Arabia`, `Kuwait`, `Qatar`, `Yemen`, `Oman`, `United Arab Emirates`, `Turkmenistan`, `Uzbekistan`, `Kazakhstan`, `Afghanistan`, `Pakistan`, `Tajikistan`, `Kyrgyzstan`, `India`, `Nepal`, `Bhutan`, `Bangladesh`, `Myanmar`, `Thailand`, `Laos`, `Vietnam`, `Combodia`, `China`, `North Korea`, `South Korea`, `Mongolia`, `Japan`, `Taiwan`, `Indonesia`, `Malaysia`, `Brunei`, `Philippines`, `East Timor`, `Papua New Guinea`, `Solomon Islands`, `Australia`, `New Caledonia`, `Vanuatu`, `New Zealand`, `Fiji`, `French Southern and Antarctic Lands`, `Egypt`, `Libya`, `Tunisia`, `Algeria`, `Morocco`, `Western Sahara`, `Mauritania`, `Mali`, `Senegal`, `Gambia`, `Guinea Bissau`, `Guinea`, `Sierra Leone`, `Liberia`, `Ivory Coast`, `Ghana`, `Togo`, `Burkina Faso`, `Benin`, `Niger`, `Nigeria`, `Chad`, `Sudan`, `Eritrea`, `Cameroon`, `Djibouti`, `Central African Republic`, `South Sudan`, `Ethiopia`, `Somaliland`, `Somalia`, `Equatorial Guinea`, `Gabon`, `Republic of Congo`, `Democratic Republic of the Congo`, `Uganda`, `Kenya`, `Rwanda`, `Burundi`, `United Republic of Tanzania`, `Angolia`, `Zambia`, `Malawi`, `Mozambique`, `Zimbabwe`, `Botswania`, `Nambia`, `South Africa`, `Lesotho`, `Swaziland`, `Madagascar`", $link);
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $res = $result[???];
    echo $res


?>
```

Пытаюсь вывести все поля из запроса select в строчку, без пробелов, так сказать одним массивом. Смотрел всякие гайды, и там обычно в строке `$res = $result[???];` идет указатель на конкретное поле. Как вывести запрос целиком?

Comment: var_dump($result);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print_r()` выводит информацию о переменной в удобочитаемом виде.

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_field,two_field) FROM test_table;
```

Это позволит несколько полей объединить в строку.